# push notification not received when app is closed Android automation

Tags: android, automation, appium, toast

I am trying to automate a scenario which involves interacting with a push notification in Android devices- specifically the push notification which is displayed when the app is closed.

After a bit of experimentation ,When the app is open/background then I can receive with the push notification but  not able to do the same when the app is closed.
Is there any way to automate this scenario for Android devices.

For Closing the app I am using line of code:

driver.closeApp();

Comment: What is the `toast message` you mean ? is from your application or other application?

Comment: toast message means push notification that we receive when application is  closed. The notification for the corresponding application are received from the server

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? Im also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

When Application is close app goes to background and `Toast` is ui thread that means `Toast` is not work with background thread.

**Try this.**

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your UI code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: If the application is in backaground we are able to receive push notification but  once the application is closed(removed from background also) after that we are not able to receive push notification.
From the server push has been sent but the device is not receiving the push notification.